# Symfony | CKEditor placeholder

Tags: ckeditor, placeholder, symfony

I'm using IvoryCKEditorBundle (http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/IvoryCKEditorBundle/index.html)

I can't find a way to add a placeholder in buildform configuration.
This is not working :

```
->add('text', CKEditorType::class, array(
            'attr' => array(
                'placeholder' => 'Your text ...'
            )
        ))
```

How can I do this ? I have to do it in JQuery ?

TY

Comment: can you try to use  'placeholder' => 'Your text ...' direct the same level of attr?

Comment: The option "placeholder" does not exist if I use it at the same level of attr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a CKEditor plugin to do that.

Download the **Configuration Helper** plugin from http://ckeditor.com/addon/confighelper and extract the folder from the zip file to the web bundles directory of your app (`web/bundles/confighelper/`).

Load the plugin in your `buildForm` method and set the placeholder as follows

```
->add('text', CKEditorType::class, array(
    'config' => array(
        'extraPlugins' => 'confighelper',
        'placeholder' => 'Your text ...',
    ),
    'plugins' => array(
        'confighelper' => array(
            'path' => '/bundles/confighelper/',
            'filename' => 'plugin.js',
        ),
    )
))
```

Answer (score 2):

i don't know if that used to be the best way, but currently the correct answer is:

```
->add('text', CKEditorType::class, array(
                'config' => array(
                    'editorplaceholder' => 'placeholder text...',
                ),
            ))
```